# Mongodb-designing schema that is scalable and efficient for chat server

Tags: database, mongodb, database-design, schema

I am currently working on a problem where I need to create a server that a marketing team can use to chat with their users. Currently, the problem statement describes that the team belonging to company X sell 3 products x,y and z. They want to connect with their customers and obtain feedback for the respective products. The question extends saying that mongodb has to be used to build the backend, ensuring that the solution proposed is scalable and efficient to other products as well(for ex products a,b and c).
For example, if I have set up a schema to store messages from clients regarding product x,y and z. I need to make sure that this solution is scalable to many other products as well.
a) What solutions/pointers do you propose to achieve a scalable and efficient database design?
b) How would you advise me to start with this problem?
Thank you

Comment: What have you tried or thought of so far?

Comment: A collection for teams(marketing team, support team etc), products, rooms/channels, users
Each room relates back to a team.
Related documents in chats collections for all chat messages in the room
Embedded Document listing all users currently in the room
Embedded Document listing all the rooms the user is currently in
Embedded Document listing all the rooms the user is allowed to be in
Each chat relates back to a room in the rooms collection
Each chat relates back to a user in the users collection

Comment: Each chat has a sentiment attached to it, can be used for analysis to answer questions like how many users like product ‘x’
Each chat related back to products collection
 Also, I am planning to use capped-collections in mongodb, they are fixed size collections with high throughput. Keeping track of latest 100 reviews for a product makes sense vs holding all reviews seen so far because products go through variety of iterations.